# .Net chat room system

Tags: .net, ajax, chat

I have a client that is requesting the addition of a chat room system to his website. The site is built on a windows server that I have no direct access to, so I'm largely restricted to working with .Net solutions. Although I could build something from the ground up, I feel it would be quite intensive to build a fully-featured chat room system into this site from scratch.

As a result, I am looking for a pre-existing chat room system that I can simply plug into his site and configure/customize it for the client's purposes. Unfortunately, I'm still trying to get the client to figure out the full scope of what he wants, so I don't really know how robust of a client he wants.

Also unfortunately, Google has mostly failed me thus far.

Does anyone know of a chat room solution that already exists, built in the .Net framework. I prefer freeware, but if you would suggest a purchased solution I could add that to the presentation as another viable option.

I'm going to continue my research as well, but would greatly appreciate experienced input from anyone who has used a .Net chat room client and would have one to recommend to me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Googled ".net chat room" 2nd result a complete app: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/ChatRoom.aspx
Here's another one:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/ASPNetChat.aspx

A nice clean solution (also free) by Steve C. Orr: <strike>http://steveorr.net/articles/webchat.aspx</strike>
Website moved, new location can be found at:
http://devproconnections.com/aspnet/webchat

Finally one by AzarmSharp: http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/224_Creating_a_Chat_Room_Using_ASP_NET_Client_Callbacks.aspx

He's had some good examples in the past for asp.net.

Comment: Thank you, this will be a great help.