# Thirdparty Chat module for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, chat

I need to integrate private chat module in an intranet like ASP.NET site, so that the users can chat privately one-to-one (like on Facebook). Integration with Active Directory and a HTML5-implementation would be a pro.

Any recommendations would be appreciated :-)

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5160042/net-chat-room-system , for example. Probably someone have already asked such question.

Answer (score 0):

For example you can use messaging service. Have a look at http://www.rabbitmq.com/ , they have .NET wrapper and API is not hard. With it you can write your own chat implementation, and not only chat(as you can send any serializable object- you can even show realtime form filling, various notifications and so on..)...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) library. There is a chat example using that library here [SignalR Chat](https://github.com/davidfowl/SignalR-Chat). It's very few lines of code, easy to change to your personal needs, and it scales very well.